# About spring-boot-admin ，Client configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I am reading the [official manual](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.1/#getting-started) in an attempt to build a `v2.0.1` `spring-boot-admin` project.When I compiled the project, an error occurred.

> "Error:(17, 23) java: Unable to access javax.servlet.Filter Could not find the class file for javax.servlet.Filter"

I am trying to add a new [dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw8Vw.jpg) to prevent this error from occurring. But it was not successful.

This is my configuration code, ask me how to do it to make the client start normally. [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPE2m.jpg)

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@SpringBootApplication

public class Adminclient21Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Adminclient21Application.class, args);
    }
    @Configuration
    public static class SecurityPermitAllConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and().csrf().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding dependency, I got the same error, resolved after adding the below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```